# Error codigo CRC en java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo, es un código para calcular el CRC (verificacion de redundancia ciclica), la cuestión es que recibe un mensaje en código binario y un generador tambien en binario, luego el código los convierte en arreglos integer, genera el el r de comprobación y une el mensaje con el r de comprobación en un solo arreglo, el problema el es que el metodo algoritmoCRC() que recibe el mensaje y el r se cae con algunos binarios y con otros no.

Clase Test

```
public class TestCRC {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AlgoritmoCRC crc = new AlgoritmoCRC();

    //String mensaje = "10011110";
    //String pGenerandor = "1001";
    String mensaje = "01001011";
    String pGenerandor = "1011";

    int tamanioMensaje = mensaje.length();
    int tamanioPGenerador = pGenerandor.length();
    crc.crearArreglos(tamanioMensaje, tamanioPGenerador);
    crc.convertirStringToArray(mensaje, pGenerandor);
    Integer[] resultadoCRC = crc.algoritmoCRC(crc.mensajes, crc.r);
    Integer[] TX = crc.combinarArreglos(crc.mensajes, resultadoCRC);
    System.out.println("CRC = " + crc.ArrayToString(resultadoCRC));
    System.out.println("TX " + crc.ArrayToString(TX));


}
```

}

Clase CRC

```
public class AlgoritmoCRC {

public Integer[] mensajes;
public Integer[] pGeneradores;
public Integer[] r;

public AlgoritmoCRC() {
    //...
}

/**
 * Metodo para convertir un arreglo de tipo Integer a String
 */
public String ArrayToString(Integer[] arreglo) {
    String dato = "";
    for (Integer numero : arreglo) {
        dato = dato + String.valueOf(numero);
    }
    return dato;
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para validar que los datos recibidos desde el mensaje y
 * pGerador sean validor de tipo 1 y 0
 */
public boolean validador(String dato) {
    int largo = dato.length();
    boolean validador = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
        if (dato.charAt(i) == '0' || dato.charAt(i) == '1') {
            validador = true;
        } else {
            validador = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return validador;
}

/**
 * Metodo para crear los arreglos en tiempo de ejecucion
 */
public void crearArreglos(int tamanioMensaje, int tamnioPGeneradores) {
    this.mensajes = new Integer[tamanioMensaje];
    this.pGeneradores = new Integer[tamnioPGeneradores];
    this.r = new Integer[tamnioPGeneradores - 1];
}

/**
 * Metodo encargado de comvertir el polinomio de String a un arreglo de
 * numeros para poder realizar los respectivos calculos se utilizara para
 * obtener los []mensaje y []pGenerador
 */
public void convertirStringToArray(String mensaje, String generador) {
    int largoMensaje = mensaje.length();
    int LargoGenerador = generador.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < largoMensaje; i++) {
        this.mensajes[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mensaje.charAt(i)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < LargoGenerador; i++) {
        this.pGeneradores[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(generador.charAt(i)));
    }
    obtenerR();
}

/**
 * Metodo para obtener el tamaño de r sabiendo que una secuentacion de 0 con
 * un tamaño igual al generador - 1
 */
public void obtenerR() {
    int largo = this.r.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
        this.r[i] = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizando para unir para unir dos arreglos en este caso
 * []mensajes con []r y luego []mensajes con el crc este metodo une el
 * arreglo de mayor tamañao primero y despues el de menor tamaño
 */
public Integer[] combinarArreglos(Integer[] arreglo1, Integer[] arreglo2) {
    int contador = 0;
    int largoArreglo1 = arreglo1.length;
    int largoNuevoArreglo = largoArreglo1 + arreglo2.length;
    Integer[] nuevoArreglo = new Integer[largoNuevoArreglo];
    for (int i = 0; i < largoNuevoArreglo; i++) {
        if (i < largoArreglo1) {
            nuevoArreglo[i] = arreglo1[i];
        } else {
            nuevoArreglo[i] = arreglo2[contador++];
        }
    }

    return nuevoArreglo;
}

/**
 * Metodo usado para realizar la operacion XOR cuando se este ejecutando el
 * algoritmo CRC se puede usaar de dos formas una usando el operador ^ o
 * devolviendo el valor dependiendo de una condicion
 */

public int operacionXor(int a, int b) {
    int resultado = 1;
    resultado = (a == 0 && b == 0) || (a == 1 && b == 1) ? resultado = 0 : resultado;
    return resultado;
}

/**
 * Metodo que contiene la logica para el calculo del CRC y que devuelve el
 * arreglo con el crc
 */
public Integer[] algoritmoCRC(Integer[] Arreglo1, Integer[] Arreglo2) {
    /**
     * Contador me dira cuantas posciones se deben bajar de la division
     * tantas como 0 a la ziquierda tenga el resto
     */
    int contadorResto = 0;
    /**
     * Variable para almacenar la posicion incial del dividendo
     */
    int contadorDividendo = 0;
    /**
     * Arreglo que almacenara los valores del resto
     */
    Integer[] aux;
    Integer[] resto;
    Integer[] crc;
    /**
     * Se hace una llamada al metodo combinar dos arreglos se obtiene los
     * largos del nuevo arreglo del pgeneradores[] se les asigna el tamaño a
     * los arreglos auxiliar y resto
     */
    Integer[] dividendo = combinarArreglos(Arreglo1, Arreglo2);
    int largoDividendo = dividendo.length;
    int largoDivisor = pGeneradores.length;
    resto = new Integer[largoDivisor];
    aux = new Integer[largoDivisor];
    crc = new Integer[largoDivisor - 1];

    /**
     * ciclo para para verificar si los primeros valor del dividendo inicia
     * con cero, si es asi se mueve cuanta posiciones tengan en cero a la
     * izquierda para asignar los primeros valor a arreglo aux[]
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < largoDividendo; i++) {
        if (dividendo[i] != 0) {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < aux.length; j++) {
                aux[contadorDividendo++] = dividendo[i + j];
            }
            contadorDividendo = i + j;
            break;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Al obtener la poscion de la asignacion actual con la variable
     * contadorDividendo se puede establecer el inicio del recorrido con el
     * primer for() el segundo for realiza la operacion xor con los primero
     * digitos binarios asignados a la variable aux[] diviendolo con el
     * pGenrardor[] la operacion se eraliza bits a bits almacenando el
     * arreglo resto[]
     *
     */

    for (int i = 0; i <= largoDividendo - contadorDividendo; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < largoDivisor; j++) {
            resto[j] = operacionXor(aux[j], pGeneradores[j]);
        }
        /**
         * el for() siguiente se utiliza para validar si el resto no tiene
         * digitos 0 a la izquierdad, si es asi se ignoran se van a
         * asignando a los primeros valores de la variable aux[] utilizando
         * el contadorResto el cual almacena el valor de la veces que se le
         * asigno un valor a aux[]
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < resto.length; j++) {
            if (resto[j] != 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < resto.length - j; k++) {
                    aux[contadorResto++] = resto[k + j];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        /**
         * el ultimo for() termina de rellenar el arreglo aux[] con los
         * valores siguientes del diviendo tomando en cuenta el
         * contadorDividendo que almacena la cantidad de bits que se han
         * recorrido en el arreglo el cual se esta operando
         */
        for (int j = contadorResto; j < aux.length; j++) {
            aux[j] = dividendo[contadorDividendo++];
        }
        contadorResto = 0;



    }

    return resto;
}
}
```

Comment: por favor indica qué error te da, y algunos ejemplos que estén fallando

Comment: indexoutofboundsexception en la linea del  ultimo for del metodo algoritmoCRC(), al parecer intenta a acceder a una posicion mas del arreglo dividiendo

Comment: Par este la solucion de crc debe ser 0111
String mensaje = "10011110";
String pGenerandor = "1001";
Par este la solucion de crc debe ser 0100
String mensaje = "01001011";
String pGenerandor = "1011";

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en esta parte del código:

```
    for (int j = contadorResto; j < aux.length; j++) {
        aux[j] = dividendo[contadorDividendo++];
    }
```

En el ejemplo que comentas, hay un momento en que `contadorDividendo` vale 12. `dividendo` sólo tiene 10 elementos, así que da un IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: Exacto la cuestion es que no se, si aplique la logica mal a establecer le metodo algoritmoCRC dado que lo buscaba era que hicera una una especie de division escalonada, el arreglo aux[] guarda los primer datos del binario, esa arreglo se opera con el metodo operacionXor con el arreglo pGenerador[] para guadar la informacion en el arreglo resto[], luego utilizo un for para que de este arreglo me guarde en el arreglo[] aux los datos sin los 0 al izquierda del primer 1 aque encunetra, luego con el contadorDividendo voy contando cuales son la posciones para asignar al arreglo aux, pero se desborda